# How to extract a .zip with php

Tags: php, xml, zip

Hello I am using the code below to download to retrieve a .zip file from a server, I do get the file however I am trying to unzip it into a folder within the same php file, but when I run my script it downloads the file, then this is the output I get:

This is the output I get:

```
File Opening Successful

Warning: ZipArchive::extractTo() [ziparchive.extractto]: Invalid or unitialized Zip object in /home/content/38/10376438/html/viptravelink/xml/xml3.php on line 48

Warning: ZipArchive::close() [ziparchive.close]: Invalid or unitialized Zip object in /home/content/38/10376438/html/viptravelink/xml/xml3.php on line 49
Uncompression Successful
```

This is the script I am using:

```
 <?php
      /*
       * XML Sender/Client.
       */
      $xmlRequest = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                     <Request>  <Source><RequestorID Client="***" EMailAddress="xml@***.com" Password="***" />    <RequestorPreferences Language="en" Currency="USD">         <RequestMode>SYNCHRONOUS</RequestMode>    </RequestorPreferences>  </Source>  <RequestDetails>        <ItemInformationDownloadRequest ItemType="hotel">
    <IncrementalDownloads>
              </IncrementalDownloads>
            </ItemInformationDownloadRequest>   </RequestDetails></Request>';

      // We send XML via CURL using POST with a http header of text/xml.

    $url = 'https://interface.demo.gta-travel.com/rbsusapi/RequestListenerServlet';  
    $ch = curl_init();
    $zipPath = '/home/content/38/10376438/html/viptravelink/xml/' .date('m-d-Y_h-i-s'). '.zip';
    $out = fopen($zipPath, 'wb'); 
    echo "File Opening Successful<br>";
    if ($out == FALSE){ 
    echo "Download Failed<br>"; 
    exit; 
    } 
      curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3); // Force SSLv3 to fix Unknown SSL Protocol error
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true ); 
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml')); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out); 
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$xmlRequest );
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER , 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS , 10);


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($out);

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
     if (!$zip) { 
            echo "Could not make ZipArchive object.<br>"; 
            exit;
    } 
    $zip->open('$zipPath');
    $zip->extractTo('/home/content/38/10376438/html/viptravelink/xml/content/');
    $zip->close();
        echo "Uncompression Successful<br>";

    ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `zip->open('$zipPath');` $zipPath variable is not initialized and your including the variable within single quotes which will not expand the variable put put the literal value as the file name. Also your setting `CURLOPT_HEADER` to 1 which will make the output include header as well causing the file to be invalid. To fix the problem. set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to 0 and set `zip->open($zipPath);`

Comment: Thankyou for your response, I changed to what you told me, the file downloaded but it didn't unzipped and this is the output:

`File Opening Successful
Warning: ZipArchive::open() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in /home/content/38/10376438/html/viptravelink/xml/xml3.php on line 47

Warning: ZipArchive::extractTo() [ziparchive.extractto]: Invalid or unitialized Zip object in /html/viptravelink/xml/xml3.php on line 48

Warning: ZipArchive::close() [ziparchive.close]: Invalid or unitialized Zip object in /html/viptravelink/xml/xml3.php on line 49
Uncompression Successful`

Comment: i made a small mistake, you can set the `$zip->open($zipPath);` and you should be ok.